# get jquery data from a list element that has a class starting with "active"

Tags: jquery

How do I get the jquery data on a list element with a class starting with "active"?
Here is my code that doesn't seem to work:

```
$("li[class^='active']").data('getthisdata');
```

the list is dynamically created, and this should be the result.

```
<li id='timeline_1' class='active sub-active'>
    <a class="timeline" href="#"'
    data-questionname = 'Comida' 
    data-timelineid = 'timelineId_101'
    data-timelineclassname = 'first' >
    <div class="circle"> <div class="bullet"></div> </div>'
    <div class="label"> Question </div>'
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: How about a fiddle we can play with?

Comment: this is correct and it will return array. process array using loop

Answer (score 0):

This will only get elements where `active` is the first class in the list of classes. Use `*=` to get all *containing* the string `active`:

```
$("li[class*='active']").data('getthisdata');
```

Or to get anything that has a class `active` (i.e. `active` is the whole name of the class):

```
$("li[class~='active']").data('getthisdata');
```